# BIRT pdf report print issue in pdf complete

Tags: pdf, birt

I have a pdf file which got exported from BIRT report. I tried opening that pdf file in adobe acrobat and tried printing it. It got printed properly.

But when I try to open the same pdf file using PDF complete and print it nothing gets printed. But the pdf file is getting opened in PDF complete properly.

Is birt pdf report not compatible with printing using pdf complete or so?

Answer (score 0):

BIRT is compatible with creating printable PDF.

There is insufficeint information here about discover the users specific issue.

What version of BIRT is being used?

How is the PDF being 'exported' (as opposed to open as)?

How is the PDF being saved?